# Copy first worksheet from CSV file to macro-enabled workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple CSV files that I want to condense into one Excel workbook, one worksheet per CSV. Manually, I would open the destination workbook (Target.xlsx), open the CSV (Source.csv), right click on the only tab in the CSV file, select `Move or Copy`, change the `To book:` field to Target.xlsx, change `Before sheet:` to Sheet3, check `Create a copy`, and close the CSV file. Here's the code I wrote to do this:

```
Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook
wbSource.Sheets(1).Copy Before:=Workbooks(wbTarget).Sheets("Sheet3") 'Type Mismatch
wbSource.Close
wbTarget.Save
```

Upon execution, I get a  "Type Mismatch" error on line 3. when I print `wbTarget.FullName` and `wbSource.FullName` I see the correct files, so I don't understand what is mismatched. Please note, I want line to 2 to stay generic so that it will work no matter which CSV file I have open.

Comment: @Comintern - In changing the variable names to be more readable, I forgot to change all of them. See edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
wbSource.Sheets(1).Copy Before:=Workbooks(wbTarget).Sheets("Sheet3")
```

to

```
wbSource.Sheets(1).Copy Before:=wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet3")
```

---

The `Workbooks` object can not have a `Workbook` object as an index, only a String or an Integer, so `Workbooks(wbTarget)` is invalid syntax.